# Session and request scopes with Spring WebFlux

Tags: spring-webflux

Currently experimenting reactive programming with **Spring Boot 2.0.0.M4**, **Spring 5.0.0.RC4** and **Reactor 3.1.0.RC1**.

Injecting a @RequestScope or @SessionScope bean into a WebFlux REST controller fails at runtime:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name 'request'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at com.adeliosys.scope.Counter$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7dce0361.increment(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.adeliosys.scope.Controller.getQuote(Controller.java:25) ~[classes/:na] // line with theScopedBean.doSometing() call in the REST controller
    (...)
```

The blocking equivalent with Spring Web MVC works fine.

I understand that reactive programming messes with thread locals, but **is request or session scoped beans injection supported by WebFlux** ?

If not, is this planed ?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Indeed, thread locals can't be used in a Spring WebFlux application, because units of work can happen on any thread at any time, and you can't expect a request to be processed on a single thread.

That type of feature could be implemented using the new [Reactor Context](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context), which allows you to attach some data to a reactive pipeline. As you've noticed, this feature is not supported currently in Spring WebFlux.